# jboss equivalent or corresponding ant taskdef ejbgen,xdoclet?

Tags: ant, jboss, jaxb, schema

i have schema's which needs to be parsed and that should create ejb stubs and jboss related deployment descriptor files .

Could anyone please suggest me which tool (for instance :xdoclet jaxb,its for weblogic) generates jboss deployment descriptor files along with ejb needed interfaces .I have been trying with the below code snippet but couldnt able to generate artifacts .

```
<taskdef name="ejbdoclet" classname="xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask" classpathref="xdoclet.classpath" />
    <taskdef name="ejbdoclet" classname="xdoclet.modules.jboss.ejb.JBossSubTask" classpathref="xdoclet.classpath" />
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
        </taskdef>
```

your help on this matter is highly appreciable .Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using ANT, I've used something like this for the build.xml. The compile task must depend on this.

```
    <target name="createDeployDescriptor" description="create DeployDescriptor using XDoclet">
            <taskdef classname="xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask" classpathref="xdoclet.classpath" name="ejbdoclet" />

            <ejbdoclet destdir="${classes.dir}/META-INF" mergedir="etc/xdoclet/merge" excludedtags="@version,@author" ejbspec="2.1" force="true">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                            <include name="**/*Bean.java" />
                            <exclude name="**/*test*" />
                    </fileset>

                    <remoteinterface destDir="${src.gen.dir}" />
                    <localinterface destDir="${src.gen.dir}" />
                    <homeinterface destDir="${src.gen.dir}" />
                    <localhomeinterface destDir="${src.gen.dir}" />
                    <!-- valueobject templateFile="etc/resources/xdoclet/valueobject.xdt" pattern="{0}" / -->
                    <!-- generate the primary key classes for the entities -->
                    <entitypk destDir="${src.gen.dir}" />
                    <utilobject destDir="${src.gen.dir}" kind="physical" cacheHomes="true" includeGUID="${xdoclet.ejb.include.guid}" pattern="{0}Locator" templateFile="etc/xdoclet/locator.xdt" />

                    <deploymentdescriptor validatexml="true">
                            <configParam name="Description" value="Deploymentdescriptor for WFink EJB2.1" />
                    </deploymentdescriptor>

                    <jboss version="4.0" mergeDir="etc/xdoclet/merge" />
            </ejbdoclet>
    </target>
```

Also Maven is possible with this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- use XDoclet to generate the EJB2 artifacts, the plugin version is defined in the root pom -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xdoclet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xdoclet</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <ejbdoclet destdir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}" includes="**/*Bean.java" />
                                <localinterface destDir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xdoclet" />
                                <localhomeinterface destDir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xdoclet" />
                                <remoteinterface destDir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xdoclet" />
                                <homeinterface destDir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xdoclet" />
                                <utilobject kind="physical" destDir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xdoclet" />
                                <deploymentdescriptor destDir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF" />
                                <jboss version="4.0" destDir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" />
                            </ejbdoclet>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ....
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

You should consider that both are out of date, for JBossAS7, WildFly and EAP6+ the generated jboss.xml descriptor is ignored and you need to add by hand a jboss-ejb3.xml which configure the JBoss specific settings.
For simple use you should not need this

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply , but i want to migrate ejbs2.1 to ejb3.0 , in my current app they have used xdoclet to generate weblogic deployment descriptors ,ejbs interfaces and ejb deployment descriptors . After googling i gotta know that xdoclet is outdated , and cant used to ejb3.0 development . Is there a way to generated ejb3.0 stubs like how used for ejb2.0 xdoclet . or annotations must be used for this ?

Comment: If you migrate to ejb3 I would use the existing tool to generate EJB2 interfaces, VO's, now you can use this generated sources and remove all the specific comments from the tool, add the ejb3 annotations where necessary, remove the ejb2 boilerplate code (like ejbCreate, ejbActivate etc). Since EJB3 I don't use a generator as you often don't need VO's (this was mostly for Entities). If you need business VO's it is better IMHO to have it under manual control as it is part of the API.  Make sense?